# Create a Pixel-Is-Point GeoTIFF using GDAL C# Bindings

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, c#, georeferencing

What is the appropriate way to create a GeoTIFF using GDAL such that the georeferencing is done based on the Pixel-Is-Point interpretation?

My assumption is that this is the best bet at ensuring that the geotiff is interpreted appropriately by another user.

I am creating a Geotiff using the C# GDAL Bindings. I am creating my output Dataset as follows (roughly):

```
Driver gtiffDriver = Gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff");
Dataset outputDataset = gtiffDriver.Create(outPath, outX, outY, numBands, DataType.GDT_Float32, null);
outputDataset.SetSpatialRef(myCRS);
outputDataset.SetGeoTransform(myGeoTransform);
```

I then write appropriate data to the raster.

So far I have tried to set the "AREA_OR_POINT" setting in the metadata to "Point" as follows:

```
outputDataset.SetMetadataItem("AREA_OR_POINT", "Point", "");
```

When opening in QGIS this setting is correctly displayed when opening properties > information. However, the raster still seems to be offset. Another possibility is that there is something I'm missing on the QGIS side here, as I am a novice user.

Edit: I should specify: I am just concerned with the half pixel offset which should occur when geo-referencing my tiff file. This is the offset that I'm referring to in the post.

Comment: Take a close look at your GeoTransform array, you've probably got them in the incorrect order. https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html The GeoTransform array is for the upper left of your image with colums increasing eastward and rows increasing southward - please double check that your myGeoTransform[5] is negative, that's a newbie gotcha.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks, that's a good shout. 

I think I wasn't clear enough about this in my question but basically the issue is just that my geotiff seems to be offset by about 0.5 pixels when it is opened in QGIS. 

I'm pretty confident that the geotransform is set correctly as the map overlays as expected apart from this smalll shift.

Comment: It sounds like you're using centre pixel coordinates, the GeoTransform should be to the upper left edge of the pixel.

Comment: @MichaelStimson okay, thanks!